# Outlook Email Signature - header?

Tags: html, css, outlook, signature

I've been trying to get a particular design to work for an email signature without any luck, I have a feeling it's not possible, but perhaps someone has a solution.

The issue is that there is a small image that needs to be *above* the first line one types on.  i.e.
[image]
[type here]
[signature details - e.g. phone no.]

If I make it normally, outlook always inserts a line break before the image and places the cursor there, I can't get the cursor to start after the image without clicking there (e.g. by pressing tab after typing subject).

I've tried making the image a background image of a div/span/table, I've tried using css to set the margin-top to a negative number, but the problem seems to stem from the fact that outlook inserts the signature after the div it creates for typing in.

Does anyone have a suggestion or is my task futile?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Outlook?

Try adding this to the image:

```
style="display:block;"
```

P.S - Backgrounds don't work in some versions of Outlook, unless you do some sort of conditional statements, you need to test how your e-mail renders in Microsoft Word (MSO rendering engine).

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Outlook 2003 and up.

Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I have already tried that.  The problem is that the cursor is still placed _before_ the image, not after.  

I am aware of the background-image issues with versions of outlook, it was mostly for testing to see if I could find any way to get it to work.

Comment: Is there any way you can provide some code for me to reproduce this with?

Comment: This should give you an example - you can use any image for the header.jpg:`<img src="header.jpg" width=640 height=54 style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
<span style="color: #009;font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt;">
<br><br><br><br>

</span>
<span style="text-decoration: underline;color: #009;font-family: sans-serif;">Jason</span><br>
<span style="font-weight: bold;padding-bottom: 5px;color: #009;font-family: sans-serif;">Sales Director</span><br>
<img src="logo.jpg" width=165 height=49>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set on `body` a `background-image` and `padding-top` equal to the height of the image.

I did something similar a while ago to fix the "cursor problem" you mentioned. I don't remember which version of Outlook it was for, but nobody ever reported any problems with it.

As Kyle R mentioned, you should definitely test how your email renders with different clients.

Comment: In regards to testing, I suggest http://litmusapp.com - it's a great tool, it costs money after your trial period has finished but there is a 14 day free trial and you can cancel at any time.

Comment: so close! I can get it to work for outlook 2003 using your method, but sadly it doesn't for 2007/2010.

Answer (score 0):

An email can be a multipart message. This means the body can have multiple encodings. Each encoding comes with its own header:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=frontier

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--frontier
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body of the message.
--frontier
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgPC9oZWFkPgogIDxib2R5PgogICAgPHA+VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUg
Ym9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZS48L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==
--frontier--
```

([example from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MIME&oldid=767736887#Multipart_messages))

In most clients the default encoding is `Content-Type: text/plain`. Adding an image however switches the encoding to eg. `base64`.

Each new encodings starts on a new line. I assume this is causing you the trouble, since this automatically puts your text/cursor below the image.
One way to get around this would be to encode the entire message as `html` - the image as well as the text, using an `img` tag, inline.

Clicking next to the image lets you do this unknowingly, I assume.